# What is the best multi-platform SVN GUI client?

Tags: linux, svn, macos

Looking for something on Mac Os and Linux mostly, and GUI, not just the command line tool.
Anybody has experience using Syncro SVN Client http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/ ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569278/your-favorite-gui-client-for-svn

Comment: Thank you - yes, I saw this before posting and this is a different question (not cross-platform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multi-platform (and even if you need a good client for one platform) I'd recommend [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/).

They have a free Foundation Edition available. Since it's a java tool, it works on almost all OS.

Comment: Thanks for the link - what is your experience with this tool?

Comment: I will try that one too - it didn't work out-of-the-box as Synchro SVN but that's worth looking at. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it once, works very well with remote servers. However, as a mac user I prefer Cornerstone as my first choice client.

Answer (score 4):

Why use a multi-platform tool? The good thing about svn is that you can use one tool on Mac OS, and a completely unrelated tool on Linux, but they'll all still talk to the same repo. On Mac, I'd recommend Versions.

Comment: I have a laptop with Linux and a desktop with Mac OS; that's the primary driver for the cross-platform requirement. I like Open Office, Firefox, and Emacs because I can reuse the same knowledge and be more efficient with the tools (at home or work).

Comment: I think that svn is the bigger learning challenge; once you have that, mastering the interface to different front ends is not too hard. I feel that trying to make one UI work on several disparate OS environments leads to a fare more disjointed experience (<cough>Java</cough>) than finding the best app on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

In a Venn-diagram sense, you are cutting it close by a Boolean AND between a) sane cross-platform GUI clients and b) SVN clients.  I'd forgo some of the requirements -- I personally like the cmdline versions as well as as the Emacs interfaces on all platforms I use, and I occasionally use the kdesvn GUI on Linux.

*Edit:* Oh wait, there is one:  [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) is a wonderful IDE, is cross-platform and has SVN integration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment
A
bout the Venn-diagram: that's what my question is - no more, no less :)

About Qt Creator: what is your experience with Qt Creator?

Comment: I really, really like Qt Creator and I say this as someone who has been using just Emacs for 15+ years. But it is a slick IDE with great help integration that I gladly use when I do some Qt coding. It is however now really tied to Qt -- you can do anything.  And it looks and feels the same on Windows and Linux (and I have no Mac...).  The version control integration I have not tried -- but I understand it does svn, git, ...  Give it a shot.

Comment: PS s/now/not/  -- it is NOT tied to Qt. You can equally well code non-Qt stuff in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dirk - not exactly what I am looking for but it's nice to know about this tool too. And I trust a 15+ years Emacs veteran :)

Answer (score 0):

Would RapidSvn located [here](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) - cross platform written in wxWindows/C++ do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) is pretty good i would say.

Answer (score -1):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is cross platform and has a plugin that enables subversion. An excellent IDE if you ask me...

Comment: I like it as an IDE, but the SVN integration isn't great.  In fact about the only reason I still have a Windows VM on my work machine is so I can use Tortoise SVN for fiddly SVN diffs.

Comment: mmh, good to know. Never tried the subvertion plugin - i assumed it was as good as the IDE.