# Seeking a VCS that works in Windows and in Linux alike

Tags: linux, windows, svn, version-control

I looked through google, but I couldn't find free source versioning system that supports both windows and linux. 
I am looking for something like TurtoiseSVN, but that can work on Linux too. Can anyone help me with my inquiry?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is merely a wrapper around SVN for windows.  Underneath the SVN is the same SVN that exists on linux.  It sounds like what you really want to ask is if there is a graphical user interface for SVN that looks and feels the same on both linux and windows?  Because underneath, svn already is the same.  You just want a common graphical wrapper?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best multi-platform SVN GUI client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964183/what-is-the-best-multi-platform-svn-gui-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of good SCMs are crossplatform systems, and all of these systems have own headaches for *cross-platform development* (EOL-style difference is the most common and well-known rake in the grass)
If you asked about usable GUI for both OS -it's another question: select your preferred GUI (they can have different concepts and ideas) and **GUI will define**, which SCM you'll use

PS: using [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

```
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ apt-get install mercurial

# Fedora
$ yum install mercurial

# Gentoo
$ emerge mercurial

# FreeBSD
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/mercurial
$ make install

# Solaris 11 Express
$ pkg install SUNWmercurial
```

(with common [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), when it's needed) you can work with Mercurial, Subversion, Git repositories transparently at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Go for git. Centralized VCS systems like SVN are in practice obsolete. Absolutely everybody is migrating to git. Git supports both platforms:

http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: He wasn't looking for a VC system, though.  He wanted a UI for one that would work in multiple platforms.

Comment: It's really not clear if he's selecting a VCS or just a SVN client.  However, I'd argue that SVN is not obsolete at all.  DVCS systems are solving a problem that a lot of people just don't have.  These solutions have benefits and tradeoffs over other systems like SVN.  The answer isn't just to use git, but to evaluate your needs.  I can also assure you that not everyone is migrating to git.

Comment: Yes, the question was a bit ambiguous. And yes, I used poetic exaggeration when I said everybody is migrating to git. What I meant was that I see an article every other week about some major project migrating to git. I don't see that for any other VCS.

Comment: The reason for the exaggeration was that I wanted to help the OP. You can evaluate your needs all day long, but the time will come, sooner than later, when you'll find out that centralized VCS systems suck. Your needs are not static.